# Cannot insert row when table is empty in MySql

Tags: mysql

I wanna insert a row when the name not exists in the table.

When the table is empty,it cannot insert anything, anyone can help me?

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO `ediftpdb`.`users`(
      name
      ,passwd
      ,vendor
    )
    SELECT
      'L001'
      ,'12345678a'
      ,'MKTPLS'
    FROM `ediftpdb`.`users`
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `ediftpdb`.`users` WHERE name='L001' AND vendor = 'MKTPLS' ) LIMIT 1;
```

P.S.
I found a funny stuff, when `ediftpdb`.`users` is empty, code like below returns nothing.

```
SELECT
  'L001'
  ,'12345678a'
  ,'MKTPLS'
FROM `ediftpdb`.`users`
```

Comment: The `SELECT 'L001' ...  FROM ediftpdb.users` will clearly return no rows when the table is empty so there will be nothing to `insert`...

Comment: It looks like you are producing a query that behaves like you have a UNIQUE index on name and vendor? Why don't you just put a index on those columns and handle the error client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way to do this is to create a unique multi-part index on name and vendor columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_vendor ON ediftpdb.users( name, vendor )
```

Then:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO ediftpdb.users ( name, passwd, vendor )
  VALUES ( 'L001', '12345678a', 'MKTPLS' )
```

will do exactly what you want to do.

Comment: I wanna insert a row when the name not exists in the table.

Comment: This does exactly what you want. Since you have unique index on name and vendor there can't be duplicate combinations of those values so when you `INSERT` and there is already name-vendor with those values in the table MySql will report an error but since you are using `INSERT IGNORE` the error message will not be generated MySql will just do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

As @Martin Smith pointed, when the table `ediftpdb.users` is empty the `FROM ediftpdb.users`
results in no rows. If it had 100 rows, then your statement would try to `INSERT` 100 (identical) records into the table.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO
     ...
    SELECT
      'L001'
      ,'12345678a'
      ,'MKTPLS'
    FROM (SELECT 1) AS dummy
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ...
```